# Need to create a custom filter for markers on Google Maps - where do I start

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I'm in a bit of a pickle here. I've set up a google maps object that shows airport locations using markers. I've even enabled clustering to a certain extent. The thing is that I need to include a filter which would allow users to:

Filter and show certain types of airports i.e by clicking on a corresponding check box
SHow markers within a certain distance from a central point. Like show all markers within a radius of # miles. A user can enter a value in a text field to see this or use a slider control.

I'm quite stuck with respect on starting this out - I need some help on this.

Answer (score 2):

What you can do is draw your circle (in response to user input).  Then draw the markers that fall within that bounds.  Each time you redraw the circle, also redraw all the markers.

```
// draw a circle of appropriate radius
var circleOptions = {
    center: destinationLatlng,
    radius: 500,  // or value from some formfield, in metres
    fillColor: "#FF0000",
    fillOpacity: 0.2,
    strokeColor: "#FF0000",
    strokeOpacity: 0.8,
    strokeWeight: 1
};

var circle = new google.maps.Circle(circleOptions);

var bounds = circle.getBounds();

// loop over your markers, and only draw the ones that are within these bounds
for (var i = 0; i < arrMarkers.length; i++) {
    if (bounds.contains(arrMarkers[i].getPosition())) {
        // only do setMap if the marker wasn't already visible 
        if (arrMarkers[i].getVisible() != true) {
            arrMarkers[i].setMap(map);
            arrMarkers[i].setVisible(true);
        }
    } else {
    // remove the ones that are not within the circle's bounds
        arrMarkers[i].setMap(null);
        arrMarkers[i].setVisible(false);
    }
}
```

You'll notice I do both setMap and setVisible.  This is so that I can then use getVisible to determine if I need to redo setMap (so avoiding unnecessary function calls to setMap - I think I had an issue with flickering).

All this should be within a function that happens in response to user input, e.g. when they submit the form that asks for the radius (or as they slide the slider).  This should also maybe be called from within your initialize function (if you want to draw a circle at the very start as well).

Of course this assumes you actually want to display a circle on your map showing that radius; I find this useful.  However if you don't, you can use exactly the same message, but just set the fillOpacity and strokeOpacity to 0.0.

Answer (score 1):

Organize references to markers into categories when you add it to map:

```
var markers = { cat1: [...markers...], cat2: [...markers...] }
```

When user selects cirtain type - just set or unset map for that markers in markers.catN

Comment: in google maps API v3 when you do `marker.setMap(mymap)` - it's being displayed, when `marker.setMap(null)` - it's being hided from map. No sure on totally relevant example, but you can look at [demo gallery](http://code.google.com/intl/ru/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/demogallery.html)